# Python filter false results out of pandas row equality

Tags: python, pandas

#### Background

I have two dataframes that are both identical in structure, that is the rows and columns number along with the column names.

#### Example

I'm trying to compare them iteratively highlighting only the difference using the below method.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Adam','Sara','John'], 'Age': [22, 25, 20], 'City':['New York','',None]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Adam','Sara','John'], 'Age': [22, 19, 20], 'City':['New York',None,'New Mexico']})
```

I am able to do such a comparison, but I can't restrict the equality to return only the False results.

```
df1.loc[1].fillna('') == df2.loc[1].fillna('') 

Name     True
Age     False
City     True
Name: 1, dtype: bool
```

I'm planning to plug it iteratively in a loop, it would be nice to highlight both values of False.

```
for i in range(1,df1.shape[0]):
    df1.loc[i].fillna('') == df2.loc[i].fillna('')
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to filter out the Boolean Series created by the comparison:

```
equality_series = df1.loc[1].fillna('') == df2.loc[1].fillna('')
equality_series[~equality_series]
```

Output:

```
Age    False
Name: 1, dtype: bool
```